# How can I get an expanded version of a dataframe which has lists as values in it?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How can I get an expanded version of a dataframe which has lists as  values in it?

Here's a sample of the dataframe I have:

```
raw = pd.DataFrame().assign(Therapuetic_Area = ['Oncology'],
LocationState = [['Ohio','Illinois','Oregon','New York']])
```

[image: Output of the raw dataframe]

Now, I need it to look like this edited DataFrame:

```
edited = pd.DataFrame().assign(Therapuetic_Area = ['Oncology','Oncology','Oncology','Oncology'],LocationState = ['Ohio','Illinois','Oregon','New York'])
```

[image: output of edited dataframe]

Is there a Pandas method I can use for this? How could I get the edited dataframe without having to manually input the values? I can't possibly manually input it because my data is enormously large. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use explode to create rows from the list values

```
raw.explode('LocationState')
```

```
Therapuetic_Area    LocationState
0   Oncology    Ohio
0   Oncology    Illinois
0   Oncology    Oregon
0   Oncology    New York
```

Comment: please just vote to close such obvious duplicates…